# Which auxiliary would be correct here?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> More than one reputable scientist **has/have** been introduced to what I am calling the spirit of wonder through an early fascination with science fiction.

Since the subject is plural, I suppose 'have' should be used, but in the sentence, 'has' was used. So, I am wondering if it was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [*More than one reputable scientist*] *has/have been introduced to what I*
> *am calling the spirit of wonder through an early fascination with*
> *science fiction*.

The bracketed subject noun phrase is singular, so the singular verb "has" is correct. We know the subject is singular because it has the singular noun "scientist" as head.

Note that "more than one" is a determinative phrase, and "reputable" is an adjective modifying the head. They are both dependents of the head, "scientist".